# Identity Server AccessTokenLifetime property and OIDC automaticSilentRenew in C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, access-token, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I would like to know which one is need to configure for Automatic Token renew, note I'm using **Identity Server Version 3.0** and **Javascript Client UI Application**

My Client configuration is

```
new Client
{
    Enabled = true,
    ClientName = "JS Client",
    ClientId = "js",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>() {
        "openid", "profile", "email", "api"
    },

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:7000/popup.html",
        "http://localhost:7000/silent-renew.html"
    },

    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:7000/index.html"
    },

    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:7000"
    },

    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60
},
```

The Current setup of Client **re-loads** the web page on **every 60 Seconds** `AccessTokenLifetime = 60`

My Javascript OIDC Configuration is

```
var settings = {
    authority: 'https://localhost:44300',
    client_id: 'js',
    popup_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:7000/popup.html',
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:7000/silent-renew.html',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:7000/index.html',

    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile email api',

    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 4,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,

    filterProtocolClaims: true
};
```

I don't know whats the purpose of **`automaticSilentRenew: true`**, because every 60 seconds it re-loads. Kindly assist me whats the actual purpose of `automaticSilentRenew: true` ? Moreover assist me whats the right way to renew the Token ?

Answer (score 0):

automaticSilentRenew is for silent authentication. When the token expires, the request will be sent to server and token will get renew automatically without user interaction ( doesn't require to type credentials on the login page) with a condition though as long as the session active on the Idsrv.

When this option enabled in your client library, on the client side you will see some iframes verifying with Idsrv session.

Reference links
[oidc specs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)

if you want to hold on the idsrv with application specific logic then, your best option is ProfileService implementation like below

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddIdentityServer().
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
}
```

implementation like

```
     public class ProfileService : ProfileService<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory;
        //Accessing HTTPContext in ASP.net Core
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
        public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(userManager, claimsFactory)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        //
        public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var sub = context.Subject.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var principal = await claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(principal.Claims);
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("Ip", GetRequestIp(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext)));
        }
        public override async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            //Check existing sessions
            var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
            var isactive = user != null;
            context.IsActive = isactive;
}
}
```